# How to replace one substring with different substrings in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings and I want to replace one common substring in all the strings with different substrings. I'm doing this in R. For example:

```
input=c("I like fruits","I like you","I like dudes")
# I need to do something like this
newStrings=c("You","We","She")
gsub("I",newStrings,input)
```

so that the output should look like:

```
"You like fruits"
"We like you"
"She like dudes"
```

However, gsub uses only the first string in newStrings. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: wow so many different solutions for one single problem, thanks all!

Comment: Do you only want to replace strings at the beginning or everywhere in the string? What happens if `I` shows up several times in a string?

Comment: @DavidArenburg good point, I wanted to consider the case which "I" may appear anywhere any number of times. I guess my example is a bit misleading.

Comment: If "I" appears in the middle of a sentence, this will lead to improper English being displayed in the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(input, "I" ,newStrings)

[1] "You like fruits" "We like you"    
[3] "She like dudes"
```

or as suggested by @ David Arenburg:

```
stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(input, "I", newStrings)
```

---

**Benchmrk**

```
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
x <- stri_rand_strings(1e3, 10)
y <- stri_rand_strings(1e3, 1)

identical(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "I", y), stringr::str_replace_all(x, fixed("I") , y))
# [1] TRUE
identical(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "I", y), diag(sapply(y, gsub, pattern = "I", x = x, fixed = TRUE)))
# [1] TRUE
identical(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "I", y), mapply(gsub, "I", y, x, USE.NAMES = FALSE, fixed = TRUE))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark("stingi: " = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "I", y),
               "stringr (optimized): " = stringr::str_replace_all(x, fixed("I") , y),
               "base::mapply (optimized): " = mapply(gsub, "I", y, x, USE.NAMES = FALSE, fixed = TRUE),
               "base::sapply (optimized): " = diag(sapply(y, gsub, pattern = "I", x = x, fixed = TRUE)))

# Unit: microseconds
#                       expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval cld
#                   stingi:     132.156    137.1165    171.5822    150.3960    194.2345    460.145   100  a 
#      stringr (optimized):     801.894    828.7730    947.1813    912.6095    968.7680   2716.708   100  a 
# base::mapply (optimized):    2827.104   2946.9400   3211.9614   3031.7375   3123.8940   8216.360   100  a 
# base::sapply (optimized):  402349.424 476545.9245 491665.8576 483410.3290 513184.3490 549489.667   100   b
```

Comment: Nice! This is more compact than my answer.

Comment: @MikeyMike, yours is a more general approach.

Comment: I'll edit your post with a benchmark soon if you don't mind

Answer (score 7):

`mapply()` can be really useful in these cases:

```
mapply(sub, "I", newStrings, input, USE.NAMES = FALSE,fixed=T)
# [1] "You like fruits" "We like you"     "She like dudes"
```

Comment: I edited your code to (1) `mapply()` to avoid `unlist()`, (2) `USE.NAMES = FALSE` to avoid `unname()`, and (3) removed the unnecessary anonymous function.  Now it's all in one call.

Comment: Maybe add `fixed  = TRUE` too

Comment: Sure, throw that in there too!  Haha.  I would also change to `sub()` as well.  I'll let him figure out the rest ;)

Comment: Thanks for the updates - this is much cleaner! I edited my post to include `fixed=T` but left out `sub()`. I figured he might want to replace all instances of "I"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sapply` for this

```
diag(sapply(newStrings,gsub,pattern="I",x=input))
```

Comment: That would be awfully inefficient both memory and performance wise